# How to make a while loop exit when user enters a certain string?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am making a survey that asks the user about age, gender, etc., using a while-loop. Is there any way to make the program exit the loop when the user enters certain strings like "cya" or "bye"?

I know that I could make an if-statement after every input, but is there an faster/easier way to do this?

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
while (user has not entered "cya"):
    age = int(input("How old? "))
    gender = input("gender? ")
```

EDIT: this example was very short, but the survey i'm making is very long, so testing every variable is too time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to perform a survey is to construct a list of all your questions, and then use that to make a dictionary of all your user details.

```
details = {}
questions = [("gender", "What is your gender?"), ("age", "How old?"), ("name", "What is your name?")]
response = ""
while response not in ("bye", "cya"):
    for detail, question in questions:
        response = input(question)
        if response in ("bye", "cya"):
            break
        details[detail] = response
    print(details)
```

Example:

```
What is your gender?M
How old?5 
What is your name?john
{'gender': 'M', 'age': '5', 'name': 'john'}

What is your gender?m
How old?bye
{'gender': 'm'}
```

Comment: But is there a way to do this with a while-loop?

Comment: I put up an example of using a while loop. However, it is more complex than the other version, so I highly recommend using the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, but when I run your code, the it doesn't loop. It just stops after asking the set of questions once?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea, but one way to achieve what you want is to throw an exception to get out of the loop.

```
    def wrap_input(prompt, exit_condition):
        x = raw_input(prompt)
        if x == exit_condition:
            raise Exception
        return x

    try:
        while True:
            age = int(wrap_input("gender ", "cya"))
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Edit: If you don't need to exit immediately then a cleaner approach is to provide your own input function which stores all input in a set which can then be checked/reset at each iteration.